# iOS/ObjC: "Fallback" tap gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController subclass whose view will generally contain some number of UIButtons and other interactive elements which may have one or more gesture recognizes attached to them.

What I'm trying to do is provide some visual feedback in the event that the user taps on a part of the screen that is not interactive. In other words: when the user taps the screen anywhere, if and only if no other control in the view responds to the touch event (including if it's, say, the start of a drag), then I want to fire off a method based on the location of the tap.

Is there a straightforward way to do this that would **not** require my attaching any additional logic to the interactive elements in the view, or that would at least allow me to attach such logic automatically by traversing the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `pointInside:withEvent:` method of the container view and return `NO` if there is an interactive element under the tapped location, and return `YES` otherwise. The case where you return `YES` will correspond to tapping on an empty location.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Perform some checks using the CGRectContainsPoint method
    // e.g. CGRectContainsPoint(oneOftheSubviews.frame, point)   
}
```

A good alternative is using the `hitTest:withEvent:` method as in the example below:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != someView) return nil;
    return hitView;
}
```

`[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]` will return the deepest view in that view's hierarchy that was tapped.

So you can check the type of `hitView`, and if it corresponds to one of your interactive subviews, return it. If it is equal to `self`, then it means that there isn't a subview under the tapped location, which in your case means that the user tapped on an empty area. In that case you'll do whatever you want to do and then return `nil`.

Comment: How would I be able to tell whether there was an interactive element there without, say, having a list of interactive elements?

Comment: (To elaborate: many of the interactive elements are contained within third-party controls, so I don't always know what they are)

Comment: Please see my updated answer. In all cases, you'll need to be able to determine whether a subview you get is one of the interactive ones you want. There isn't an automagical way to do what you need. But you won't need to add any custom logic to your subviews.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for, but as you say, I think what I'm hoping for is probably not actually possible. Ended up making a UIView subclass with an NSArray property holding all the UIViews to which it should cede touches, and using the pointInside method.

Comment: I think that you could have used the `hitTest` method to determine whether the user tapped on a `UIControl` subclass or not. It shouldn't matter whether they are standard controls or 3rd party ones.